# jQuery- How to target just a single list item for removal

Tags: jquery

I have a to do list and I'm having issues removing a single line item when delete button is pressed. With my current code, it only removes the actual delete button and not the list item. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Goal: Hover over a list item and press the remove icon to remove it from the list.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 //Declare variables
 var $newItem = $('#newItem');
 var $addBtn = $('#addBtn');
 var $textField = $('#textField');
 var $textAddForm = $('#textAddForm');
 var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
 var $list = $('ul');
 var $glyph = $('.glyphicon')

 //hide the Add form until it's needed and put focus on newItem
 $textAddForm.hide();
 $newItem.focus();

 //hide draggable tooltip on mouseover
 $wrapper.mouseover(function() {
  $('#draggable').fadeOut(1000);
 });


 //Make the list draggable
 $wrapper.draggable();
 $wrapper.resizable();

 //Hides the newItem button and adds the text field and add button
 $newItem.on('click', function(){
  $newItem.hide();
  $textAddForm.show();
  $textField.focus();
 });

 //Grabs the submission from Add Item
 $textAddForm.on('submit', function(e){
  var grabText = $textField.val();
  var $listItems = $('#listItems ul');

  //disables page from submitting and appends the text to list
  e.preventDefault();
  $listItems.prepend('<li>' + grabText + '<span class="hidden glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></li>');

  //After inserting item, hides it and re-enable the New Item button
  $newItem.show();
  $textAddForm.hide();
  $textField.val('');
  $newItem.focus();
 });


 //Toggle complete 
 $list.on('click', 'li', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var copy = $(this).detach();
  var hasComplete = $this.hasClass('complete');

  $this.toggleClass('complete');

  if (hasComplete === true) {
   $this.remove();
   copy.prependTo('ul');
  }
  else {
   $this.remove();
   copy.appendTo('ul');
  }

 });

 //show Delete button on mouseover and remove if it's pressed
 $list.on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'li' , function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $thisitem = $this.html();
  console.log($thisitem);
  $('.glyphicon', this).toggleClass('hidden');

  $glyph.on('click', function(){
   $thisitem.remove();
  });
 }); 

}); //end
```

```css
body {
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 background: orange;
}

h1, h2, li {
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

p {
 font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}

@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

.glyphicon {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 float: right;
} 

.glyphicon:hover {
 color: red;
} 

.hidden {
 visibility: hidden;
}

#logo {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#logo h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}

#logo p {
 margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
 border-style: solid;
 width: 340px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: auto auto;

}

#newItem {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#textField {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

#listItems {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 22px;

}

.complete {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>The little to do</title>
  <meta carset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Summon Fonts & Library-->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">


 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="draggable">
  <p>I'm draggable!</p>
 </div>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo">
   <h1>Project Bacon</h1>
   <p>The Electronic Shopping List</p> 
  </div><!--end logo-->

  <div id="listTitle">
   <h2>BUY GROCERIES</h2>
   <div id="listItems">
    <ul>
    </ul>
   </div><!--end listItems-->
   
   <form id="textAddForm">
    <div>
     <input id="textField" type="text" name="entry" placeholder="Add item...">
    </div>
    <div id="addBtn">
     <input type="submit" name="addBtn" value="Add" type="button">
    </div>
   </form><!--end textAddForm-->

   <div id="newItemForm">
    <button id="newItem" type="button">New Item</button>
   </div><!--end newItemForm-->

  </div><!--end listTitle-->




 </div><!--end wrapper-->

 <!--Summon JS-->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `else {
   $this.remove();
   copy.appendTo('ul');
  }` Applying breakpoint on $this.remove() reflects your desired result and the statement after that undo your desired behavior it seems. If that gives you any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you omit the filter for the click handler you can define different behavior depending on what element is clicked. In this case the remove button does the remove, and clicking the line item will toggle the completed status (cross it off the list).

Given a selector for the remove button element, you can use `.closest("li")` to locate and remove the parent `LI` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Declare variables
  var $newItem = $('#newItem');
  var $addBtn = $('#addBtn');
  var $textField = $('#textField');
  var $textAddForm = $('#textAddForm');
  var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
  var $list = $('ul');
  var $glyph = $('.glyphicon')

  //hide the Add form until it's needed and put focus on newItem
  $textAddForm.hide();
  $newItem.focus();

  //hide draggable tooltip on mouseover
  $wrapper.mouseover(function() {
    $('#draggable').fadeOut(1000);
  });


  //Make the list draggable
  $wrapper.draggable();
  $wrapper.resizable();

  //Hides the newItem button and adds the text field and add button
  $newItem.on('click', function() {
    $newItem.hide();
    $textAddForm.show();
    $textField.focus();
  });

  //Grabs the submission from Add Item
  $textAddForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    var grabText = $textField.val();
    var $listItems = $('#listItems ul');

    //disables page from submitting and appends the text to list
    e.preventDefault();
    $listItems.prepend('<li>' + grabText + '<span class="hidden glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></li>');

    //After inserting item, hides it and re-enable the New Item button
    $newItem.show();
    $textAddForm.hide();
    $textField.val('');
    $newItem.focus();
  });


  //Toggle complete 
  $list.on('click', function(e) {
    var $targ = $(e.target);
    if ($targ.hasClass("glyphicon")) {
      // remove button clicked
      $targ.closest("li").remove();
    } else if ($targ.is("li")) {
      // toggle complete status of line
      var copy = $targ.detach();
      var hasComplete = $targ.hasClass('complete');
      $targ.toggleClass('complete').remove();
      if (hasComplete) {
        copy.prependTo('ul');
      } else {
        $targ.remove();
        copy.appendTo('ul');
      }
    }
  });

  //show Delete button on mouseover and remove if it's pressed
  $list.on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'li', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $thisitem = $this.html();
    console.log($thisitem);
    $('.glyphicon', this).toggleClass('hidden');

    $glyph.on('click', function() {
      $thisitem.remove();
    });
  });

}); //end
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: orange;
}
h1,
h2,
li {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
 .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  float: right;
}
.glyphicon:hover {
  color: red;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#logo {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#logo h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
#logo p {
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 340px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto auto;
}
#newItem {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#textField {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#listItems {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.complete {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>The little to do</title>
  <meta carset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Summon Fonts & Library-->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <div id="draggable">
    <p>I'm draggable!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">
      <h1>Project Bacon</h1>
      <p>The Electronic Shopping List</p>
    </div>
    <!--end logo-->

    <div id="listTitle">
      <h2>BUY GROCERIES</h2>
      <div id="listItems">
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--end listItems-->

      <form id="textAddForm">
        <div>
          <input id="textField" type="text" name="entry" placeholder="Add item...">
        </div>
        <div id="addBtn">
          <input type="submit" name="addBtn" value="Add" type="button">
        </div>
      </form>
      <!--end textAddForm-->

      <div id="newItemForm">
        <button id="newItem" type="button">New Item</button>
      </div>
      <!--end newItemForm-->

    </div>
    <!--end listTitle-->




  </div>
  <!--end wrapper-->

  <!--Summon JS-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks so much for introducing me to the event.target and closest calls. I just read the differences between event.target and $this and didn't know it existed and will be extremely useful for me in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you explained the functionality thoroughly, it seems right now the line item can only have a remove option when it's been completed (strike through). The problem it seems is that you're running remove then re-prepending the element to the list on this line here:

```
if (hasComplete === true) {
    $this.remove();
    //copy.prependTo('ul');
}
```

By commenting out the prepend it works to my understanding of the functionality:

https://jsfiddle.net/ac83xodj/